# How to create a Mailbox in Postfix in /var/spool/mail

Tags: postfix

I want to create a mailbox to receive emails obviously but don't have any idea, how to do it.

I configured the `main.cf` to dont create the `Maildir` structure, for specific reasons I need my mailbox in the old way in `/var/spool/mail`.
Someone told me that only send a mail is necessary but I sended email to an unexisting account with

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" test@mydomain.com
```

But didn't work, I also used an External ESP but it didn't worked either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is most likely nothing to do with the mailbox settings, rather to do with `posfix` not accepting incoming email.  Your `MX` records for `mydomain.com` need to point to your VPS; the firewall on your VPS needs to allow connections on port 25; the VPS provider must not have blocked port 25; and `postfix` must be listening (accepting connections) on port 25 (`netstat -an | grep :25`). Then the email address must exist on the VPS.  Check these things, **look in your mail log**, and update the question with the exact results.  Otherwise you are asking for a basic tutorial which already exists.

Comment: Ill edit my post to the recent progress

Comment: I can connect to 25 using telnet

Comment: mailog added to the edition

Comment: The last update is that if i send to bounces@mail.mydomain.com instead of bounces@mydomain.com the mail reachs the mailbox but if I send to bounces@mydomain.com i get error `dsn=5.4.6`

Answer (score 1):

### Configuration error

You didn't provide any of your configuration, but the error is quite revealing:

```
dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for domain.com loops back to myself)
```

From this it seems your configuration is missing `domain.com` either from [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) or [`virtual_alias_domains`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains) in `main.cf`, whichever better fits your needs. Please take a look at the [Postfix Basic Configuration](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html) – with this question especially the chapter [What domains to receive mail for](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#mydestination).

### Additional problems with DNS

Your current (as of Oct 24, 2020) MX records are:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain.com.         3399    IN      MX      1 domain.com.
domain.com.         3399    IN      MX      1 mail.domain.com.
```

However, the `mail.domain.com` doesn't exists with an `A` record.

Comment: Now it's pointing to the same IP address than `honeymails.com`, which doesn't really increase redundancy at all. Frankly, it seems this is far from the "Best E-Mail Marketing Platform To Really Grow Your Business" it claims at the [site](http://honeymails.com/).